# Custom dialag on page unload in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    $('#myModal').modal();    // open bootstrap modal, etc, not important
    return false;
});
```

here is my code. How can I hide default confirm window and bind buttons "Leave page" and "Stay on page" to appropriate actions in my boostrap modal?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "you can't".

[The only thing you can do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload) in `beforeunload` is to set the `returnValue` to have the browser UI ask the user if they really want to leave.